# Generic method type can't be used as generic type for generic class

Tags: c#

I want to implement a generic method that should create an instance of a double generic object.
The generic types of this class that should be instantiated are another class and an interface which the first type must implement.
When I call new in the generic method with its generic type I get the compiler error `CS0311` even if I restrict the type correctly to my base interface.
Why can't I create an instance like this?

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetQuery<ITESTEntity>();
    }

    static void GetQuery<I>() where I : IEntityBase
    {
        var qry = new myQuery<TESTEntity, I>();
    }
}

class myQuery<T, I> 
    where T : class, I
    where I : IEntityBase
{

}
```

Comment: The error in question is: "Compiler Error CS0311 | The type 'type1' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method '<name>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'type1' to 'type2'. | When a constraint is applied to a generic type parameter, an implicit identity or reference conversion must exist from the concrete argument to the type of the constraint."

Comment: Does `ITESTEntity` actually implement `IEntityBase`?  Show us the code of `ITESTEntity` please. Considering `GetQuery<ITESTEntity>();` has to be the line the error occurs on, it is really important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have these definitions:

```
interface IEntityBase { }

interface ITESTEntity : IEntityBase { }

class TESTEntity : ITESTEntity { }
```

Then your problem stems from here:

```
class myQuery<T, I> 
    where T : class, I
    where I : IEntityBase
```

You're stating that `T` must be assignable to `I`, and `I` must be assignable to `IEntityBase`. That's fine, but here:

```
static void GetQuery<I>() where I : IEntityBase
{
    var qry = new myQuery<TESTEntity, I>();
```

You're accepting any `I` that's assignable to `IEntityBase`. So you could also call it like this:

```
interface ITESTEntity2 : IEntityBase { }

class TESTEntity2 : ITESTEntity2 { }

GetQuery<ITESTEntity2>();
```

This call would be valid, but now in your method `GetQuery()`:

```
new myQuery<TESTEntity, I>();
```

`I` will be `ITESTEntity2`, to which `TESTEntity` is not assignable. It can't be guaranteed that `TESTEntity` is assignable to any `I` where `I` is assignable to `IEntityBase`, as demonstrated above with `ITESTEntity2`.

So reconsider your design.